# How to rerun Python justpy apps in Visual Studio Code without having to stop the process?

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, justpy

I am using the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) in Visual Studio Code and I use the green triangle button to run Python files. [image]

However, that button doesn't rerun the file if the file is already running if I am working with a Flask or justpy app. If the app is already running and I press the button for a second time, I get the following output in the VS Code terminal:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 "/Users/me/app/app1.py"
```

Instead of that I expect to get something like this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 "/Users/me/app/app1.py"
JustPy ready to go on http://127.0.0.1:8002
```

PyCharm is able to rerun a running justpy app, but not VSC. Is there a setting I should maybe change in VSC? Here is a sample justpy app if you want to give it a try:

```
import justpy as jp

def hello_world():
    wp = jp.WebPage()
    d = jp.Div(text='Hello world!')
    wp.add(d)
    return wp

jp.justpy(hello_world)
```

Edit: There is a workaround and that is to press CTRL + C or CMD + C in the terminal to stop the process and then run again, but that's just too cumbersome.

Comment: In VS Code, we use the command "_python -m flask run_" to execute flask or click _F5_ to debug it, and the run button provided by the "Python" extension is to execute "Run Python file in Terminal".

Answer (score 0):

for flask apps when you set the debug=true, it will always automatically rerun on vscode when you save your file